# ¿Que es lo que hace una --fake migrations en django exactamente?

Tags: django, django-models

Corri el comando python manage.py migrate app --fake y funciono no tengo ningun error, pero no tengo idea de porque hacer esto funciono y no me quiero quedar con ese hueco en el proyecto... que es lo que hace exactamente --fake.

Comment: Has probado a leer la documentacion?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de django estas corriendo?

Comment: tal vez si la pregunta sea medio obvia para alquien con ya bastante experiencia, lei la documentacion y logre entender que evita hacer cambios en la base de datos y que sobreescribe las anteriores migraciones, pero par que quiero hacer eso ? algo me despejo mi duda leer los docs pero igual no me queda claro, estoy usando la ultima de django 1.10.5

Answer (score 1):

Este comando esta pensado para trabajar con bases de datos ya en producción, con la estructura previamente definida o datos ya insertados.

Además sobreentendemos que las tablas por naturaleza ya tienen las misma estructura que las definidas en el proyecto Django. Por tanto aplicamos un `--fake` evitando que se ejecuten las migraciones anteriores, se marquen como ya ejecutados en la tabla `migrations` y poder aplicar migraciones nuevas.

Answer (score 0):

El sistema de migraciones en Django permite la trazabilidad de los cambios en la estructura de las tablas de una base de datos. No necesariamente se aplica en producción, porque es muy frecuente su uso durante el desarrollo de un proyecto.

Como decía, es un registro de cambios, es decir, de las diferencias entre la versión actual de un modelo y la versión inmediata anterior. Ojo con *inmediata anterior* porque es la clave del parámetro `--fake`.

La migración, compara las diferencias entre ambas versiones y crea un archivo que crea los cambios en la base de datos. Por ejemplo, si en la nueva versión creas un nuevo campo, se crea un script que crea ese campo en la base de datos y llena los registros existentes, si los hubiere, con un valor por default, definido por el programador.

Para poder reconstruir una base de datos, entonces, es necesario recorrer todo el camino trazado, desde la migración inicial, una a una, hasta la última.

Pero que pasa estás programando en dos equipos o es un equipo de programadores quienes contribuyen al proyecto. Imagina que la versión del modelo actual es la 5 y en tu equipo estás en la versión 3.

Con el parámetro `--fake` es te saltas todas las migraciones faltantes (en este caso la 4) y dejas a tu modelo con la versión final (o sea la 5).

En realidad, usarlo en producción es un poco más arriesgado que usarlo en desarrollo, porque puede haber faltantes de datos en la tabla final.

Por último, no olvides incluir las migraciones en tu control de versiones para asegurar que cuentas con la traza completa de los cambios en tu base de datos.